# Pointing a File object to a directory Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file

I want to be able to write to this file called "records.csv", it works if I specify the exact directory URL of "records.csv". But the program wouldn't work on another computer..

So I am trying to find out how to point to "records.csv", and it is in the same folder as my .fla

This is my saveFile function:

```
function saveFile():void
{
    var file:File = File.applicationDirectory; 
    file = file.resolvePath('records.csv');
    // create a stream object to read/write, and open in APPEND mode
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);
    // add a new line to the text file;
    stream.writeUTFBytes("\n" + (speedometerBox.text) + ',' + (rpmBox.text) + ',' + (carbonometerBox.text) + "\n" );
}
```

I have tried using userDirectory, documentsDirectory, desktopDirectory, applicationStorageDirectory but they do not work.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Are you using air? If no ,you cannot write in to file , only send to server

Comment: I think he is, since he wrote that it works in the manually set folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change to:

```
var file:File = new File()
function selectFolder():void{
   file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveFile);
   file.browseForDirectory();
}

function saveFile(e:Event):void
{
    file = file.resolvePath('records.csv');
    // create a stream object to read/write, and open in APPEND mode
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);
    // add a new line to the text file;
    stream.writeUTFBytes("\n" + (speedometerBox.text) + ',' + (rpmBox.text) + ',' + (carbonometerBox.text) + "\n" );
}
```